# PHP: Help in Retrieving and Echoing Multidimensional Array ID

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm looking to display a list of available weapons of a game, based on items listed in an array. I'm able to display information suck as 'Attribute Values' and 'Price' perfectly via a foreach loop, however being a PHP newbie, I'm having a lot of trouble working out how to echo each item's ID, such as 'Short Sword', 'Middle Sword', 'Long Sword', etc. I thought I was getting close using key($sword)... but no dice. Here's what I'm working with:

```
<?php $item_swords = Array();

$item_swords["Short Sword"] = Array (
"Attribute Value" => 5,
"Price" => 100,
);

$item_swords["Middle Sword"] = Array (
"Attribute Value" => 8,
"Price" => 250,
);

$item_swords["Long Sword"] = Array (
"Attribute Value" => 12,
"Price" => 750,
); ?>

<?php foreach ($item_swords as $sword) { ?>
  <li>
    <img src="<?php echo $sword["Item Sprite"]; ?>">
    <span><?php echo $sword; ?></span>
    <div>ATT +<?php echo $sword["Attribute Value"]; ?></div>
    <div><?php echo $sword["Price"]; ?>G</div>
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

If anyone could lend a hand and help demonstrate how best to echo an item's ID or a per item basis throughout my loop, then that would be very awesome indeed. Thank you for your time.

Comment: no such value like `$sword["Item Sprite"]`

Comment: array name or variable name with space is not a good practice.

Comment: Apologies - I had drastically reduced the clutter of the index values in order to make things more readable. That area works just fine in my test environment - I had unfortunately neglected to omit it from the original post. I will update that section now.

Edit: Seems I am unable to edit the original post. Apologies again for the confusion regarding the Item Sprite line.

Comment: Add the output you are currently getting, and what you want instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this code

use `key` attr in `foreach` loop

and echo `$key` value instead of `array like $sword`

```
<?php $item_swords = Array();
$item_swords["Short Sword"] = Array (
    "Attribute Value" => 5,
    "Price" => 100,
);
$item_swords["Middle Sword"] = Array (
    "Attribute Value" => 8,
    "Price" => 250,
);
$item_swords["Long Sword"] = Array (
    "Attribute Value" => 12,
    "Price" => 750,
); ?>
<?php foreach ($item_swords as $key=>$sword) { ?>
<li>
    <img src="
<?php //echo $sword["Item Sprite"]; ?>">
    <span><?php echo $key; ?></span>
    <div>
        ATT +
        <?php echo $sword["Attribute Value"]; ?></div>
    <div>
        <?php echo $sword["Price"]; ?>G
    </div>
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This works flawlessly - thank you very much. It is strange, I was sure I had used an identical method myself, but it appears that I must have carried over an error somewhere. Regardless - this sorted it. Cheers!